# Getting the contents of a directory excluding everything inside .git in bash

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I need to get the number of the contents of a directory that is a git repository.

I have to get the number of:

```
1) Other directories inside the directory I am currently iterating (and the other sub-directories inside them if they exist)

2) .txt files inside the directory and its sub-directories

3) All the non-txt files inside the directory and its sub-directories
```

In all the above cases I must ignore the **.git** directory, along with all the files and directories that are inside of it.

Also I must use bash script exclusively. I can't use another programing language.

Right now I am using the following commands to achieve this:

1. To get all the `.txt` files I use : `find . -type f \( -name "*.txt" \)`. There are no `.txt` files inside `.git` so this is working.
2. To get all the `non-txt` files I use: `find . -type f \( ! -name "*.txt" \)`. The problem is that I also get all the files from `.git` and I don't know how to ignore them.
3. To get all the `directories` and `sub-directories` I use: `find . -type d`. I don't know how to ignore the `.git` directory and it's sub-directories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to just add these extra tests:

```
find . ! -path './.git/*' ! -path ./.git -type f -name '*.txt'
```

The problem with this is `./.git` is still traversed, unnecessarily, which takes time.

Instead, `-prune` can be used. `-prune` is not a test (like `-path`, or `-type`). It's an *action*. The action is "don't descend the current path, if it's a directory". It must be used separately to the print action.

```
# task 1
find . -path './.git' -prune -o -type f -name '*.txt' -print

# task 2
find . -path './.git' -prune -o -type f ! -name '*.txt' -print

# task 3
find . -path './.git' -prune -o -type d -print
```

- If `-print` isn't specified, `./.git` is also printed as the default action.
- I used `-path ./.git`, because you said "the `.git` directory". If for some reason there are other `.git` directories in the tree, they *will* be traversed and printed. To ignore *all* directories in the tree named `.git`, replace `-path ./.git` with `-name .git`.

Comment: Thanks you so much. It work perfectly. I just want to ask one question. When I use `find . -path './.git' -prune -o -type d -print` I get a `.` directory. Does this represents the current directory? Also, how can I ignore it in the output?

Comment: @SimosNeopoulos Yes I was nearly going to mention that. It is the current directory, specified with `find .`. This prefix will be included if it matches. It doesn't match in the first two because of `-type f`. You can do: `find . -mindepth 1 -path './.git' -prune -o -type d -print` or `find . -path './.git' -prune -o -type d ! -path . -print`.

Comment: Personally, I would use `-name .git -prune`, as Git won't store anything named `.git` (for security reasons) and hence the simpler `-name` test matches what Git does as well. But either works, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes writing a bash loop is more clear than a one-liner

```
for f in $(find .); do
    if [[ -d $f && "$f" == "./.git" ]]; then
        echo "skipping dir $f";
    else
        echo "do something with $f";
    fi;
done
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I ran the code but I still get all the .git files and folders

Comment: you have to change my example so it fits your needs - all the components you need are there ...